# Accidental rollback - any penalties involved?

Tags: support, editing

If my edit gets rolled back, will there be a (relevant) negative log associated with my account? If so can the roll back be undone if it has been applied by accident?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no penalty involved at all. If the rollback is wrong, feel free to perform another rollback to the correct version (and perhaps leave a comment why you're doing this) but do not get involved in a so-called [rollback war](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75906/295232); at that point, it's better to invoke the moderators by raising a custom flag.